# How to Correctly Assign values from a text file to a 2d Matrix in C#

Tags: c#, matrix, console-application

I am going through a problem I cannot see the way out though it is simple.

I am reading a file and assigning it to an array:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TheMaze\TheMaze\Data\" + FileName + ".txt");

map = new MapFile();

            int width = lines[0].Replace(" ", "").Length;
            int height = lines.Length;

            map.Matrix = new byte[width, height];



            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                string line = lines[y].Replace(" ", "");

                for (int x = 0; x < line.Length;x++)

                {

                    //

                }

                Console.ReadKey();
            }


        }

        return map;
    }
```

I just dont get how to assign the values from the file correctly to my matrix object.

To which variable the values should be assigned?

I tried `map.Matrix[x,y] = line[x]`
but I get an error since I have to convert x to byte.

on my class MapFile I have only this variable: `public byte[,] Matrix = null;`

If I convert line[x] to byte all the values are printed later as 35.

I am kind of completely lost and appreciate any help.

[image: The File structure I have:]

That is just a text file I manually wrote.

Comment: You dont have to convert ``x`` to ``byte`` but the return value of ``line[x]``. Try the following ``map.Matrix[x,y] = Convert.ToByte(line[x]);`` If your file has a number in each line, you will have to write ``map.Matrix[x,y] = Convert.ToByte(int.Parse(line[x]));``

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
My file is actually made of  '#', '.', 'S', 'F'
Where # are walls, '.' are valid paths, 'S' the start point and 'F' the end point.

Comment: Can you pls post a sample of your file, just a few lines should be enough.

Comment: It sounds like you need to map the characters in your file to byte values. Its hard to tell without more information about what you are trying to do. Can you show some example lines, and then an example of what you expect the matrix to look like when populated with data from that line?

Comment: Btw, any reason your Matrix has to be an byte array, why dont you use string array ? So instead of ``map.Matrix = new byte[width, height];`` just say ``map.Matrix = new string[width, height];`` or ``char[width, height];``

Comment: Actually, I dont see a problem in your code... when I use the following: ``var b1 = (byte)'#'; var b2 = (byte)'.'; var b3 = (byte)'S'; var b4 = (byte)'F'; `` - I get the correct values 35, 46, 83, 70.

Comment: @BrianFlynn yes, I did it converting the line[x] to byte and it works. But to check if it really works I have to write another class "MapDisplay" and then read the map.Matrix from the ReadMap method. There I will iterate through every point and write on the screen.

Thank you guys for the insights and help given!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version just for fun :]

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"..\..\Data\" + FileName + ".txt");

foreach (char c in text.Replace(" ", ""))
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)(c & 15);
    Console.Write(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the variables height and width to my MapFile Class to make it easier to track the size of the array.

The code was changed only from here:

```
for (int y = 0; y < map.height; y++)
            {
                string line = lines[y].Replace(" ", "");


                for (int x = 0; x < map.width;x++)

                {
                    map.Matrix[x,y] = Convert.ToByte(line[x]);

                    if (line[x] == '#')
                    {
                        map.Matrix[x, y] = 1;
                    }

                    if (line[x] == '.')
                    {
                        map.Matrix[x, y] = 2;
                    }

                    if (line[x] == 'S')
                    {
                        map.Matrix[x, y] = 3;
                    }

                    if (line[x] == 'F')
                    {
                        map.Matrix[x, y] = 5;
                    }
                }
            }
```

And on my MapDisplay class I have now:

```
for(int y = 0; y < map.height; y++)
        {


            Console.WriteLine();

            for (int x = 0; x<map.width; x++)
            {

                Console.Write(map.Matrix[x, y]);
            }
        }
```

With the Right output from my matrix:

[image: With the Right output from my matrix:]

Now to make the Maze Look a little bit better I changed the Background and Foregound color of the output this way:

```
for(int y = 0; y < map.height; y++)
        {


            Console.WriteLine();

            for (int x = 0; x<map.width; x++)
            {
                if (map.Matrix[x, y] == 3)
                {

                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.Write("3");
                    Console.ResetColor();


                }
                else if (map.Matrix[x, y] == 2)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    Console.Write("2");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
                else if (map.Matrix[x, y] == 5)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.Write("5");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
                else if (map.Matrix[x, y] == 1)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                    Console.Write("1");
                }

            }
        }
```

Output with different colours:
[image: Colored Maze Output]